# Queryset AttributeError: the 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Keywords(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="users",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    searchedword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Because I need to add the Keywords model twice to the admin,  I use subclass the Keywords model as a ProxyModel:

```
class keywordsProxy(keywords):
    class Meta:
    proxy = True
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(keywordsProxy)
class keywordsProxyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   list_display = ('searchedword','get_cword')
   def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super().get_queryset(request)
       return qs.values('searchedword').annotate(cword=Count('searchedword'))

   def get_cword(self, instance):
       return instance.cword
   get_cword.short_description = "count"
```

I want to display count of searched words like this:

```
 searchedword  count
 python         3
 java           2  
 .              .
 .              .
 .              .
```

But I got :

> **'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'**

I changed query to:

```
 return qs.annotate(cword=Count('searchedword'))
```

or

```
 return keywordsProxy.objects.all().annotate(cword=Count("searchedword"))
```

or

```
  return keywords.objects.annotate(cword=Count('searchedword'))
```

but result will be not correct:

```
 searchedword  count
 python         1
 python         1
 python         1
 java           1
 java           1
```

And log error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "../site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "../site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "../site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "../site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/base.py", line 33, in render
    return super().render(context)
  File "../site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 344, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl)),
  File "../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 320, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 311, in __init__
    super().__init__(*items)
  File "../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 234, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 260, in lookup_field
    print("meta = ",obj._meta)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Any help on how to solve this is welcome.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you register in admin keywordsProxy, not original model? What s the purpose of keywordsProxy? And also it would be great if you show the whole traceback, not just an error message.

Comment: Thank you @EugenePrikazchikov. I edited the post.